# Sufficient and Necessary Conditions for Chiral Symmetry Breaking

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking, chirality

In their [2005 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0505265), the authors write (just below eq. 3.19)

> we see that a non-zero value of $F_0$ is a necessary and sufficient criterion for spontaneous chiral symmetry breaking. On the other hand, (...) a non-vanishing scalar quark condensate $\langle \bar qq\rangle$ is a sufficient (but not a necessary) condition for a spontaneous symmetry breakdown in QCD

Why is it that

- $F_0\neq 0$: necessary and sufficient for ChSB
- $\langle \bar qq\rangle\neq 0$: sufficient, but not necessary for ChSB

---

**Additional notes**

- $F_0$ is a decay constant, as in $$ \langle 0|A^a_\mu |\pi^b\rangle = \text{i} F_0 \delta^{ab} p_\mu  $$
- If I understand correctly,

$$ F_0\neq 0 \color{red}\Leftrightarrow \text{ChSB}\quad\text{and}\quad \langle \bar qq\rangle\neq 0 \color{red}\Rightarrow \text{ChSB} $$

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning why/how $Q_A^a |0\rangle\neq 0$ leads to $\langle \bar qq\rangle=0$. In order to assume that $\langle \bar uu+\bar dd-2\bar ss\rangle=c\neq 0$, we'd have to assume a broken $Q_V^8$ from $SU(N)_V$..?

Comment: Nononono... you are misreading the logic: S&S, sec 3.2.2, *show* you that $Q^a_A|0\rangle \neq 0$ *allows* a scalar condensate to be 0, it certainly *does not lead* to it. It does compel a nonvanishing asymmetric condensate, as stated! The logic flow point is, however unlikely or undesirable that is, the scalar condensate is up for grabs.

Comment: See, that's the thing: I don't see where they show that $\langle S^0\rangle = \langle \bar qq\rangle = \langle \bar uu+\bar dd+\bar ss\rangle=0$ is allowed when $A_A^a|0\rangle \neq 0$. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: There is nothing they can do to restrict it! (Like they did (3.14) --> (3.15).) Eqn (3.11) gives no traction to the SU(3) generators, so you know nothing about the scalar condensate, at this level. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252744/physical-meaning-of-the-chiral-condensate-in-qcd/315061#315061) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I think I can narrow down my question: If we assume $\langle\bar qq\rangle=0$ in eq. (3.16), which must lead to $\langle \bar uu\rangle = \langle \bar dd\rangle = \langle \bar ss\rangle = 0$, it also leads to 0 on the r.h.s. of eq. (3.18). And now, **either** $P^a$ **or** $Q_A^a$ can have a *non-zero* matrix element with the vacuum and the massless state $\phi_a$. So even with $\langle \bar qq\rangle = 0$, we *could* have a non-zero $F_0$, which definitely implies SSB. Is this chain of thoughts valid?

Comment: I think so. However, it's hard to imagine non-vanishing matrix elements for $Q^a_A$ but vanishing  for the pseudoscalar density $P^a$. In my answer's toy example, I assumed a subtle SU(3) $Q_V$ breaking of the vacuum, perhaps explicit, I think, which you definitely lack here, with *all* three scalar condensates vanishing! If *that* is your question, the S&S assertion is weakened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand correctly,
$$ F_0\neq 0 \qquad \color{red}\Leftrightarrow \qquad\chi SB \tag{↯} \\
\langle \bar qq\rangle\neq 0 \qquad\color{red}\Rightarrow \qquad\chi SB . $$

In the latter case, of course, a charge annihilating the vacuum in (3.18) dictates a vanishing r.h.s.

However, conversely, imagine a (complete, fantasy) contrapositive hypothetical, in which 
$$
\langle \bar qq\rangle = 0
$$
but, for whatever unrealistic reason, you also have
$$
\langle \bar uu + \bar dd -2\bar ss \rangle =c\neq 0, \qquad  \Longrightarrow  \\
\langle \bar uu + \bar dd \rangle = \langle   2\bar ss \rangle +c,
$$
which is to say $Q^A_8|0\rangle \neq 0$; so, for $c=-3 \langle   \bar ss \rangle  $  you may still have $\chi SB$, cf. (3.17), *a=8*.

For the former case, (↯), reversing the implications of the contrapositives and mindful that $F_0\sim v$ in the crucial (2.21) of section 2.2, an axial charge annihilating the vacuum will perforce dictate a vanishing $v \sim F_0$.

Conversely, the entire argument of (2.22) has no force behind it for vanishing $v \sim F_0$: you do not *need* massless states popped out of the vacuum by chiral charges, anymore. This is the "normal" chiral symmetry case where ***all*** fields have $\langle 0|\Phi ^b|0 \rangle =0$, so $\langle 0|Q_A^a|\phi^b \rangle =0$ for all *a,b* s, that is all *Q* s kill the vacuum (it is not as though they project it to  spaces orthogonal to all states).

Comment: I think you would have to explain what prevents $\langle\bar{q}q\rangle$ from acquiring a VEV. There is an old idea that it could be a discrete symmetry.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, this is *resoundingly off the table* in this question, a strictly technical issue of logical implications, not the essence of chiral symmetry. I am *not* addressing mechanisms of condensation or anything of the sort--I thought my dismissive comments of detail made that clear. I am *only* illustrating *how* the premise is *unnecessary*, despite its being sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your point. 1) There is no need to be dismissive, whether $\chi SB$ breaking implies a non-zero vev of $\bar{q}q$ is a legitimate question. 2) In general the answer would surely seem to be yes; once chiral symmetry breaking is broken, what would prevent $\bar{q}q$ from acquiring a vev? In QM and QFT, everything that is allowed is mandatory. 3) A possble answer is a discrete symmetry, like a $Z_2$.

Comment: I am only answering the OP's question on logical implications, not what actually happens in QCD, or alternative mechanisms: this is not a forum for alternate $\chi SB$ scenarios and their causes and mechanisms. Perhaps you wish to ask a separate, disjoint question on that, but steering the OP's attention there might well not argue away his puzzlement.

Comment: Maybe I am still misreading your argument. What is your claim? You argue that $\langle\bar{q}q\rangle \Rightarrow  \chi SB$ but not $\langle\bar{q}q\rangle \Leftrightarrow  \chi SB$? Or do you argue that indeed $\langle\bar{q}q\rangle \Rightarrow  \chi SB$, but you have no opinion on the reverse implication?

Comment: Sigh... Logic! I thought I made it clear. I am *confirming* that $\chi SB$ does *not* require a nonvanishing $\langle \bar q q\rangle$, as long as there are different non-vanishing condensates: This is the point Scherer and Schindler make, and it is a sound one.

Comment: But then my original comment does appear to be relevant: I think your example (having $\langle\bar{q}^aq^a\rangle=0$, but individual flavor condensates not zero) does not work. 1) In the $m=0$ limit this would require flavor symmetry breaking (forbidden by Witten-Vafa). 2) For $m_a\neq 0 $  this would not really be $\chi SB$. In addition, it requires fine-tuning, and would at most be true at a single renormalization scale (and then fail at any other scale).

Comment: This is really just an illustration of the fact that in QFT a statement of the type $\langle\bar{q}q\rangle =0$ requires a symmetry to protect it. Usually, that is chiral symmetry. But once you have $\chi SB$ what would be the symmetry?

Comment: The OP most definitely did *not* ask for realism, the causes of $\chi SB$, or even QFT. He is trying to understand a primitive current algebra statement in S&S.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that we have learned things since the days of current algebra, and that the statement in S&S is not correct

Comment: ...in the contexts of your own choice. End of argument. Ask another question.

Comment: Due to your helpful comments on the question post above, I'll choose this answer as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I think what people have in mind when the say that is the following:

1) (Spontaneous) Chiral symmetry breaking implies the existence of Goldstone modes, and the symmetries of the effective lagrangian then imply a non-zero coupling of the Goldstone mode to the axial current. $F_\pi$ then has to be non-zero.

2) We could imagine, however, that the order parameter is not $\langle \bar\psi\psi\rangle$, but some other operator sensitive to chiral symmetry, say $\langle \bar\psi\sigma\cdot G\psi\rangle$, or $\langle (\bar\psi\Gamma\psi)^2\rangle$, for a suitable matrix $\Gamma$.

3) The problem with this idea is that we need to explain what prevents $\langle \bar\psi\psi\rangle$ from acquiring a VEV once chiral symmetry breaking is broken by some other order parameter. A possible suggestion is that there is an unbroken discrete symmetry (a $Z_2$, for example) that prevents bilinears from acquiring a VEV, but allows four fermion operators. In QCD, this is known as the [Stern scenario](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9801282).

4) In the context of QCD, the Stern scenario was shown to be ruled out on general grounds, most recently using [discrete anomaly matching](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07666). I am not aware of any theories that exhibit generalized chiral symmetry breaking, but there are cases where it is realized approximately, most notably in the [CFL phase](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9804403) of high density QCD.

5) To summarize: $F_\pi\neq 0$ is indeed necessary and sufficient. In general, it is clear that $\langle\bar{q}q\rangle\neq 0$ is sufficient, but not that it is necessary. In QCD (and other gauge theories), however, we can show that it is also necessary.