# Difference between $SU(2)_L $ and $SU(2)_R$

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, group-representations

Like my title, what is the difference between $SU(2)_L$ and $SU(2)_R$? I know they transform differently, but I don't know how to write down the transformation. I'm not familiar with group theory, so I would very much appreciate a detailed answer.

Comment: in which context you are asking this question? is it left-right symmetric model?

Comment: Yes, I get why the left handed and right handed doublets look like that, but I don't know how to write down the covariant derivative for the newly introduced higgs field, and I guess this has some thing to do with the difference between $SU(2)_L$ and $SU(2)_R$.

Comment: To reopen this question (v1), consider to provide context and/or references.

Comment: Related question, conceptually identical, [102575](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/102575/lie-algebra-of-axial-charges).

Comment: SU(2)_L means that the gauge transformation applies only to left-handed particles (treating right-handed particles as singlets under these transformations), SU(2)_R would correspondingly describe an (additional) interaction in which only right-handed fermions participate. The group structure of them (taken individually) is the same but the fact that SU(2)_R is often added in addition to SU(2)_L leads to additional gauge bosons etc.