# axial anomaly for adjoint fermion v.s. fundamental fermion

Tags: mathematical-physics, representation-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, lie-algebra, quantum-anomalies

It is known that the axial anomaly (chiral anomaly, the left L- right R) shows that $U(1)_A$-axial symmetry is not a global symmetry at quantum level.

In particular, one can consider the (1) fundamental fermion and (2) adjoit fermion for QCD. The $U(1)_A$-axial symmetry is not a symmetry for both cases, but there are discrete sectors that survive as a symmetry within $U(1)_A$.

What are the remained discrete axial symmetries for (1) fundamental fermion and (2) adjoint fermion, say for a Lie group G (like SU(N))?

Answer (score 2):

The discrete symmetry is the symmetry of the corresponding 't Hooft vertex. For an $SU(N_c)$ gauge group this symmetry is $Z_{N_f}$ in the case of [fundamental](http://inspirehep.net/record/3438?ln=en) fermions, and $Z_{N_c}$ in the case of [adjoint](http://inspirehep.net/record/191830?ln=en) fermions.